# Strange behaviour in updating a nested dict with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
q_dict = {'Paper Name': 'Paper 8.jpg', 'Category': 1, 'Questions': {'Question 1': {'Question Type': 1, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 2': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 3': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 4': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 5': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 6': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 7': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 8': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 9': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 10': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 11': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 12': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 13': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 14': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 15': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}}}
```

Basically there are 15 questions from `Question 1` to `Question 15` as a nested dictionary in parent `Questions` dictionary.

But now I want to update this dictionary with this list which also has 15 questions:

```
new_list = ['Question 6', 'Question 7', 'Question 8', 'Question 9', 'Question 10', 'Question 11', 'Question 12', 'Question 13', 'Question 14', 'Question 15', 'Question 16', 'Question 17', 'Question 18', 'Question 19', 'Question 20']
```

It's just `Question n + 5` in human language.

But I've struggled with this whole day. The strange behaviour I'm observing is:

**Method 1-**

```
for ind, val in enumerate(list(q_dict['Questions'].keys())):
    q_dict['Questions'][new_list[ind]] = q_dict['Questions'].pop(val)
```

And the result is:

```
{'Paper Name': 'Paper 8.jpg', 'Category': 1, 'Questions': {'Question 16': {'Question Type': 1, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 17': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 18': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 19': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 20': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}}}
```

**Method 2-**

```
for ind, val in enumerate(list(q_dict['Questions'].keys())):
    q_dict['Questions'][new_list[ind]] = q_dict['Questions'][val]
    del q_dict['Questions'][val]
```

Result:

```
{'Paper Name': 'Paper 8.jpg', 'Category': 1, 'Questions': {'Question 6': {'Question Type': 1, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 7': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 8': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 9': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 10': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}}}
```

EDIT:
Expected Result is:

```
q_dict = {'Paper Name': 'Paper 8.jpg', 'Category': 1, 'Questions': {'Question 6': {'Question Type': 1, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 7': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 8': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 9': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 10': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 11': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 12': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 13': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 14': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 15': {'Question Type': 4, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 16': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 17': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 18': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 19': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}, 'Question 20': {'Question Type': 3, 'Question Point': [], 'Expected Answers': [], 'Student Answers': []}}}
```

It must be something I'm missing, or doing wrong since I'm really new to Python programming. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I added expected result in order to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often a bad idea to add or remove elements from a list you're iterating over, as the behavior may not be what you expect. Instead, replace the questions dict entirely:

```
q_dict['Questions'] = {
    name: entry for name, entry in zip(new_list, q_dict['Questions'].values())}
```

Note that, before Python 3.6, you may need to sort the values as iteration order is not guaranteed.

Comment: It just makes the q_dict starting from Question 6 to Question 10. I want it to be Question 6 to Question 20 (basically question number + 5 in q_dict)

Comment: @humanymn This solution gives output from 6 to 20. 6 to 21 doesn't make sense because that would be 16 questions and there are only 15 in the input.

Comment: I'm so sorry you're right, I was printing from the last cell. Sorry! Thank you very much for your time and answer. I'm so glad.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share another way to solve this issue, which not involve extra list for keys (just adding 5 to each question key):

```
import re
def change_name(m_str):
    a = re.match('\D+(\d+)', m_str)
    return m_str.replace(str(a.groups()[0]), str(int(a.groups()[0])+5))


q_dict["Questions"] = {change_name(inner_key):inner_val for inner_key, inner_val in q_dict["Questions"].items()}
```